# Error: 'unknown account' in Send Transaction using web3.js for Binance Smart Chain Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, web3js, binance-smart-chain

I'm learning to write smart contract. I've written code in solidity and fully tested (change and read both methods) in localhost using [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) .

The problem arises when I deployed the contract on Binance Smart Chain (testnet) and calling (change) method of my smart-contract, the error occurs and it says **"unknown account"**.

I can see my deployed contract on [testnet.bscscan.com](https://testnet.bscscan.com/) But I'm not sure about the user I'm creating via code and I also tried my other user public/private key where I have BNB faucet, in both ways I'm receiving same error **"unknown account"**.

I think the error is related to user.
In below code I'm just trying to create a post that will save the data in blockchain.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/'))

//const account = web3.eth.accounts.create(); <-- also tried public/private key obtained by this
//console.log(account);

web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(USER_PRIVATE_KEY)
const SC = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS)

SC.methods.addPost().send({ from: USER_PUBLIC_KEY }, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('An error occured', err)
      return
    }
    console.log('Post: ', res)
})
```